# How to say on a resume that you lost your job because management was spooked by a pending Labor Fairness Act that was later shot down by the courts?

Tags: resume, law

I believe that management at the non-profit I was working at was spooked by the at-the-time [pending changes to the Fair Labor Standards Act](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15063/what-citations-of-the-fair-labor-standards-act-federal-law-made-4-million-employ), which would have reclassified my position as being eligible for overtime pay and required my employer to start paying me significantly more, since I was working a lot more than 40 hours a week. Though the changes have recently been blocked by courts in several states<sup>[[1]](http://www.californiaemploymentlawreport.com/2016/11/u-s-federal-court-judge-puts-dol-overtime-rules-hold/)[[2]](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/legal-and-compliance/employment-law/pages/judge-blocks-flsa-overtime-rule.aspx)</sup>, in the mean time I've already lost that job.

So how should I state this on a resume when they ask about reason for leaving?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49393/discussion-on-question-by-leeand00-how-to-say-on-a-resume-that-you-lost-your-job).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not being fired, that is being laid off. In the interview, you simply say that you were laid off for due to a budget reduction.

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify the the reason for leaving a job (or being laid off, or being fired) on a resume.

If you're asked, you explain the situation during the interview.

Otherwise, there is no need to explain it.

Comment: ...and only if asked.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z good point, I'll update my answer!

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Correct; I was asked.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. Generally, you want to keep your responses to questions about why you left your last position short and simple, and they don't belong on a resume.

For example, the short answer to why you left your last position is that you were laid off. That's what it boils down to, and that's all you need to tell any potential employer. There's no point in getting into the details regarding why they thought they wouldn't be able to afford to employ you anymore, or about laws and court decisions and such.

If anybody tries to press you on it, it's perfectly appropriate to say something to the effect of that you aren't privy to or aren't comfortable discussing the financial position of your previous employer, and would rather discuss the things that you did for them and what you can do for your potential new employer.